# jquery ui draggable restricting div to up and down drag within containment

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have been learning Javascript lately. As an exercise I wanted to create a Dominoes board. I am trying to drag a tile around the board. The approach I took is to create a tile within the board and set it to `draggable` with jquery ui. 
However, somehow the drag is confined to up and down movement only. Why is that??

**Html:**

```
   <div id="board">
      <div id="tile_1-0" > 
        <div class="dominoe"> </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

**css:**

```
.dominoe {
/* Dominoe shape */
    position: relative;
    height:60px;
    width:30px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 2px solid black;

/* Rounded Corners */
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding:2px;    
}

#board {
        margin: auto;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #0A9D2D;
}
```

**javascript:**

```
$( "#tile_1-0" ).draggable({containment:'#board'});
```

Please take a look at the embedded fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/totoorozco/t5nnd95j/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the div it's in takes up the full width of the 'board'. Fix that by setting the display of that div to inline-block:

```
#tile_1-0 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/wwbvqdsf/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

add this to your css:

```
#tile_1-0{
   position: absolute;
}
```